# Why is GDAX charging maker's fee when using API?

Tags: coinbase.com, gdax

Why are we getting charged maker's fee when creating buy orders on the GDAX API.

For example I deposited 100 EUR to GDAX account and wanted to place a limit buying order for size 0.5 ETH at the price of 200 EUR and received HTTP 400: "Insufficient funds" as a response.

I lowered the size to 0.4 and the order went through, but I was left with 19.80 EUR on my account - meaning that 0.25% was taken as well, but my order was at 200 EUR and 0.4 ETH, totaling 80 EUR not 80.2 EUR.

Looking at the API there shouldn't be a maker's fee.

Has anyone else noticed this?

Doing it manually in the GUI I am left with 20 EUR.

Answer (score 2):

There is no maker fee using API, but when place new order, the default parameter for "post_only" is false, which means it is possible set a price to become a taker, hence GDAX will make sure you have enough funds to cover the fees.

Set post_only to true then GDAX will allow you to spend your entire account without reserves for fees.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly why this would happen, but according to the [SEC](https://www.sec.gov/spotlight/emsac/memo-maker-taker-fees-on-equities-exchanges.pdf):

"If an execution occurs, the liquidity providing “maker” receives a rebate, and the “taker” that executes against that resting order pays a fee to the market."

This means the **maker** is the one who already had their trade order in the books, and the **taker** is the one who places the order and who's order is executed immediately against the makers.

Using the API, you could've accidentally placed a buy order below or at the current price or ETH. If this happened you would be charged a "taker" fee instead of the 0% maker fee. That is my only explanation, because it says [here](https://docs.gdax.com/#fees) in there API docs there is zero maker fee.

If you were the maker but charged the taker fee, I'd ask GDAX why this is occurring [here](https://support.gdax.com/customer/portal/emails/new)

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the fills tab you can see which order(s) your order was matched with. You can also see if your order was executed as a maker or a taker. It likely executed as a taker, which is why you had to pay the fee.